# Read and store a variable number of arguments java

Tags: java, variables

I am trying to read data in a java program of the form 
Booking id month date numdays type1 number1 type2 number2 . . .

e.g. Booking 1 Jan 25 2 single 1 double 1, The first four elements of a line 
will always be in the same format and so are easy (i.e. id, month
date numdays  but I'm unsure how to read in the (typex numberx arguments which there could be any number of, then store them?.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Map` for the extra attributes:

```
class Booking {
    private final int id;
    private final LocalDate date;
    private final int numDays;
    private final Map<String, Integer> attributes;

    ......
}
```

Comment: What condition can I use to access theses variables?. I am reading in a input from a txt file.

Comment: while(inputStream.next() !="\n"){  
                 String nextType = inputStream.next();  
                 System.out.println("here");  
                 int nextCapacity= inputStream.nextInt();  
                 System.out.println("here2");  
                 Map<String, Integer> requests=new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 
                 requests.put(nextType,nextCapacity);
                 System.out.println("Up to here 2");
                 
              }    I thought something like this would work but it appears to be breaking @Misha

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively could define number x / type x as class and use a list of such elements.